# jQuery Plugin for multiple line-item forms

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins

I have a form that acts as a frontend to entities in a 1:many relationship. The form lets the user edit the properties for the parent entity, as well as add, edit, and delete properties for the child entities.

This is such a common scenario that I expect someone has already come up with an elegant jQuery plugin to help make a user-friendly form. However, I haven't found one yet (I don't think I'm hitting quite the right combination of Google keywords).

Can anyone suggest a jQuery plugin that helps create forms for editing child entitites/line items?

Comment: Ah! To use Google we all need to know something before hand - the right keywords. Not perfect. :)

Answer (score 0):

not a "plug-in" but a good example of using jquery, with reusable code, to do it in rails
http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Comment: As it happens, rbates' example code is exactly what I'm trying to work my way out of. :-P